# Reverse scrolling behaviour wanted

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

How to achieve the following functionality? When the scroll-bar reaches the certain point, I need to scroll up for a certain amount of pixels?

Not that good with JS/jQuery, maybe to bind scroll event to document, but really don't know how to achieve this.

This is what I have, but it doesn't work:

```
  $(document).bind('scroll',function(e){

            if (
                    $(this).offset().top  > 3000) 
            {
                $.scrollTo('-800px', 800, { axis:'y' });
            }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try comparing `document.body.scrollTop` with `document.body.clientHeight`. If it reaches your desired point use the `scrollBy()` method to go up some pixels.

EDIT after your update:
You’re mixing up `scrollTo` (scroll to absolute position on your page) and `scrollBy` (scroll up or down from the current scroll position). Also, these are no jQuery methods, so use them without the `$.`

EDIT 2:
You can’t use `offset()` for the scroll position. It only gets the position of an element on your page.

Here’s a working example:

```
$(document).bind('scroll', function(){
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 3000) {
        scrollBy(0, -800);
    }
});
```